# Cannot compile C program via command prompt, even though PATH variable is set

Tags: c, windows, gcc, mingw

[image: MinGW]

I am using Windows 10 in a Virtual Machine (on Ubuntu). As you can see from the image, I have MinGW installed, and my Path variable set to C:\MinGW\bin. The gcc.exe file is present.

However, when I try to compile and run a simple C program, I get "gcc is unrecognized". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On Command prompt, if you go to mingw/bin directory and give `gcc` command, what do you get? No input file or gcc is unrecognized?

Comment: Have you closed command-prompt and re-opened it again? After changing PATH variable you have to re-open command-prompt.

Comment: It says it's unrecognized, and yes I've closed and reopened cmd.

Comment: And the file I'm trying to compile is on the Desktop, so I cd into Desktop and try it from there.

Comment: Ok...weird...I turned my machine on this morning and it worked!